Cannot logout nor switch user in Ubuntu 22.04
I got this problem after a fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04.5 on a Dell Vostro (Intel i5). There is no Nvidia or AMD graphics card.
Whenever I click the "Log Out" or "Switch User" button on the top right of the desktop, I get a black screen. The only thing that I can do from the black screen is to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to restart Ubuntu.

Ubuntu 17.04 was the last Ubuntu Desktop release that used lightdm; as at 17.10 the default desktop was switched to GNOME3 which uses the gdm3 as its DisplayManager (it's a GNOME program).  Your question contains incorrect details, and doesn't actually provide a question; as it's already suggesting a solution to a problem that isn't clearly defined.

A fresh installation of Ubuntu 22.04 would be using the default display manager for Ubuntu 22.04 which is gdm3 as mentioned in the previous comment.

It seems that this problem is caused by gdm3, since Ubuntu 22.04 uses gdm3 as the default display manager instead of lightdm display manager which is used in the previous version.
Use the more lightweight lightdm instead of the default gdm3 (GNOME Display Manager) as the default display manager.
sudo apt install lightdm
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm


I remember that I installed lightdm as a replacement for gdm3 in Ubuntu 18.04 to solve a boot problem and somehow this substitution managed to solve this boot problem.
